# How to know that the stream has ended C#

Tags: c#, stream

I'm trying to recieve a tcp packet in C# but I don't know when can I stop reading from the stream.
Here's what I've tried:

```
for(int i = 0; i < stm.Length; i += chunkSize)
{
    bb = new byte[chunkSize];
    k = stm.Read(bb, 0, bb.Length);
    ns.Write(bb, 0, k);
}
```

But it threw me an error about that the stream is not seekable.
So I've tried this:

```
int k = chunkSize;

while (k == chunkSize)
{
    bb = new byte[chunkSize];
    k = stm.Read(bb, 0, bb.Length);
    ns.Write(bb, 0, k);
}
```

Is there anything to do?
Thanks :)

Comment: Why don't you Google for "How to read from a TCP-Stream in C#"? There must be 1000ds of explanations available.

Comment: I believe setting k equal to chunkSize might be problematic. Look what stream.Read() returns. It doesn't always equal to what you might expect.

Answer (score 4):

Here we go:

```
int read;
while((read = stm.Read(bb, 0, bb.Length)) > 0) {
    // process "read"-many bytes from bb
    ns.Write(bb, 0, read);
}
```

"read" will be non-positive at the end of the stream, and only at the end of the stream.

Or more simply (in 4.0):

```
stm.CopyTo(ns);
```

Comment: The problem with that is that the code freezes on the Read method if there's nothing to read.. I guess there's timeout or something, but I don't think it's the right solution to wait until timeout at the end of every packet

Comment: @JohnSmith Then you'll want to use something like Select() to determine if there is data ready to be read.

Comment: @John yes, you just perfectly described the behaviour of Read. If you don't want that, you'll have to use one of the async APIs, and sometimes disable "nagle" on the sending socket

Comment: @JohnSmith, if you are concerned about synchronous read - use asynchronous versions instead - check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337900.aspx which covers BeginRead and related methods.

Answer (score 1):

a **binary reader** is what you would require since it knows exactly how many bytes to read!

It prefixes the length of the bytes and so it knows how much to read!

Comment: A binary-reader only does that in a few very specific scenarios, and isn't at all useful if the protocol is defined elsewhere. Frankly I do a lot of comms/protocol/serialization/etc code, and I use BinaryReader exactly never.

Comment: hahaha....i knew i was wrong...thxx for ur info..
but isn't it helpful to read strings..

Comment: I didn't say "wrong" - just... over-enthusiastic perhaps. With strings: again, whether that is useful depends exactly on how the wire protocol says that they are stored. For example, this week I've been writing WebSocket framers; there are (essentially) 2 WebSocket protocols and both handle strings - this wouldn't help with either of them. Nor would it help with strings in the redis protocol, or in the protobuf protocol, etc...